# Attaching Christmas lights to peak of roof

Tags: lighting, roof

[image]

I'm trying to attach some christmas lights to the peaked section if this roof. The flat part is easy with gutter clips but I'm really struggling with the peak because I don't have access any higher than the flat section of roof, so I need to do it using a pole or something.

Any ideas gratefully received

Comment: How do you have access to the flat portion but not the peak?  Would a longer ladder help?  I can't picture your scenario.

Comment: To rephrase - I can't reach the peaked section from my ladder and I'm reluctant to go and buy a new one- but maybe that's the only option.

Comment: depending on materials, you might be able to use strong magnets; i attach fairy lights to nail heads in that manner...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the rooftop of the lower section of roof, you can climb on the roof and access the gable from above. Using clips (e.g.: [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Dyno-Seasonal-Solutions-73020-20COSCC-Once-N-Forever-Clips-For-Holiday-Lights-20-Pk/45821238?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=1060&adid=22222222227033130899&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=76978265111&wl4=aud-310687321882:pla-133675948151&wl5=9061198&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=112550001&wl11=online&wl12=45821238&wl13=&veh=sem%20Walmart)) you can subsequently use a pole to place and remove lights.
When walking on a tile roof, walk on the peaks of the tiles to reduce risk of damaging them.
Obviously care should be taken to not slip and fall off the roof.
Maybe this year you can hire a light installing company or a handyman to install the clips.

Comment: Alternately you could *rent* a taller ladder one time to place the clips.